# How to use JS require() without Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

This is probably a lame question, but how can you achieve the same thing as `require()` (Node.js) in regular JavaScript?

Some help would really be appreciated.

Comment: you have to use eval and sync ajax to re-create node.js's require() function. needless to say, most devs don't like either so they use less-handy async importing like yepnope, requireJS, AMD, etc.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are several services that let you do this.

The most popular is [Browserify](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify).

Basically, it entails going through the file reading through the syntax tree and converting it to the a style similar to what RequireJS does.

Note that this requires an extra compilation step. (We will eventually get modules in ES6 though so there's that :) )

Comment: 2017 - most popular is webpack

Answer (score 8):

http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html

A module loader called RequireJS exists for in-browser use without the use of Node.js or Rhino.

To use it download and save the script and include it in your page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Sample Project</title>
        <!-- data-main attribute tells require.js to load
             scripts/main.js after require.js loads. -->
        <script data-main="scripts/main" src="scripts/require.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>My Sample Project</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

The data-main attribute will point to your main script where you can load the rest of your scripts using:

```
require(["helper/util"], function(util) {
    //This function is called when scripts/helper/util.js is loaded.
    //If util.js calls define(), then this function is not fired until
    //util's dependencies have loaded, and the util argument will hold
    //the module value for "helper/util".
});
```

Checkout the documents at http://requirejs.org for more information.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! requirejs works fine for me. I'm using gulp to concat + uglify node modules to one file (ex : script.min.js) and using requirejs to compile properly the modules.